# Contact data de-duplication design considerations

Tags: apex

**Problem statement**

We have been discussing a requirement related to de-duplication of Contacts records in Salesforce. Unfortunately, we cannot use a package from AppExchange because of limited budget, so we need to design our own custom solution for the same. The total number of Contacts is around 1 Million and the expected number of duplicate contacts is close to 50000.

We are looking to get some recommendations / best practices from all the experts here on how should be approach the design. Following are the design points (in chronological order) that we have considered. Please feel free to correct me, if wrong.

**Design Steps**

1. Design a Batch Apex that runs through all the Contacts, identifies duplicate Contacts records based on certain criteria and assigns a common Id (some text generated based on concatenated field values). The purpose of this common Id is to make sure that we already know the records that will be merged together. I think there should also be a flag that identifies the master record among the duplicates.
2. Design a second Batch Apex that runs through the identified duplicate records from step 1 and issues "merge" DML statement to combine the duplicate records with the master record.

Since "merge" operation also moves the related records from merged to master record, we want to use this DML statement but then we can only merge master with maximum 2 records. We may also run into issues if the number of duplicates per contact exceeds more than what is allowed by Salesforce.

Kindly suggest if the above design considerations are good or we need to incorporate other points as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: At that data volume, I would be building a solution that runs on a separate server or desktop machine using the Salesforce API. Is using DemandTools also eliminated on price considerations?

Comment: @DavidReed - To be honest, I have no knowledge about DemandTools. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: Well, I can see this - https://www.crmfusion.com/demandtools/ . I can check this one. However, if you have some inputs on my technique written above, please do provide.

Comment: I think it will be extremely challenging to get that solution to run well within the platform limits, especially if your matching rules are not very simple.

Comment: Consider matching rules are pretty straightforward. For instance, email Id and Phone.

Comment: DemandTools would be my first choice and second choice.  I agree with David Reed about platform limits, esp governor limits and non-selective query issues.

Comment: Thanks guys. Since you have recommended DemandTools, I will check what the cost would be.

Answer (score 0):

Few considerations that you should think of ,apart from solving the duplicates issues

1. Is this de-duplication design , would also check for duplicates
   for incoming contact records ?
2. does contacts have any related records like leads ?
3. do you import contacts ?
4. are there any integrations out there that send you contacts on daily/quarterly or whatever?
5. do users in the system create contacts ? if yes,do you intend to show duplicates to them ?
6. are there integrations into your system that send you contact information and its respective related records ?
7. are there any integrations that send you contact information and you are supposed respond back to them with a unique Id or success/failure message within a specified SLA time ?
8. Merging of these duplicate records would be a potential confusion , if there are 2 different users who were working on these duplicate contacts , how do you manage them ?
9. Parameters you consider for de-duping like email,phone,name etc ?
10. are those de-dupe parameters are *required* to create a contact ?

You can make use of salesforce inbuilt duplicate management rules for UI and build your own custom logic in-line with the duplicate rules.You may refer

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_namespace_datacloud.htm

Comment: Thank you. However, do you agree with the design we are considering?